# Unfortunately, ... Has stopped caused by calling a method

Tags: java, android

I get the error "Unfortunately, "Cards" has stopped." when running my Android application ("Cards" is my app name).
I think it is caused by the MainActivity (OnCreate) calling a method from another Java file, I just don't know how to fix it.

I have two Java files.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Box_Middle1 bm1 = new Box_Middle1();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bm1.MiddleCard(); //Calling the method
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.contacts");
    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
}
public void onClick2(View v)
{
    Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.settings");
    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

BoxBottom (second Java file)

```
public class Box_Middle1 extends ActionBarActivity{

public void MiddleCard()
{

    /***********************************************************************************
     * CARD GRIDVIEW
     * Middle
     **********************************************************************************/

    ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

    //Create a Card
    Card card = new Card(this);

    //Create a CardHeader
    CardHeader header = new CardHeader(this);

    //Add Header to card
    card.addCardHeader(header);

    cards.add(card);

    CardGridArrayAdapter mCardArrayAdapter = new CardGridArrayAdapter(this,cards);

    CardGridView gridView = (CardGridView) this.findViewById(R.id.bottomGrid);

    if (gridView!=null){
        gridView.setAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);
    }
}
}
```

And the LogCat:
[Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8cbb393dfc04f685bd24)

Thanks.

BTW I'm using [this](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/) library

Comment: _I think it is caused by the MainActivity_ Don't just *think*, open up the logcat and see the exact exception. (And post it there)

Comment: `bm1` is never intialized, neither declared. On the other hand you should never used the new operator on an Activity object

Comment: what is bmi in your mainactivity??

Comment: @kgandroid sorry I posted the wrong code - fixed it

Comment: What does `MiddleCard()` do?

Comment: @rudi `MiddleCard` is a method within the Box_Middle1 activity

Comment: Use something like `onCreate(){... bm1 = new Box_Middle1(); ...}` Class Box_Middle1 uses Android system service.

Comment: An activity object inside activity! Reconsider your design!

Answer (score 1):

As `Box_Middle1` is an activity class and uses Android system service. As you can see in the log, System services not available to Activities before onCreate(). You tried to initialize it before the activity started executing onCreate(). Thus change
`Box_Middle1 bm1 = new Box_Middle1();`

to
  Box_Middle1 bm1;
    onCreate(){
        ...
        bm1 = new Box_Middle1();
        ...
    }

**Edit**
Now I see that, `Box_Middle1  is an activity class!` You should consider your design. If you extended `ActionBarActivity` for the sake of Context and you do not intend it to be an activity, you may use the context as follows, otherwise read about [Fragments](https://www.google.com.et/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Ftraining%2Fbasics%2Ffragments%2F&ei=CKi_U9O9Koqy0QXk7IDoDQ&usg=AFQjCNFzhNB-ak8tVr-nS13r685Ygna2lQ&bvm=bv.70810081,d.ZGU):

```
public class Box_Middle1 {
    Context context;
    public void MiddleCard(Context context){
        ...
        this.context=context;
        Card card = new Card(context);
        ...
    }
}
```

And call it from MainActivity like:

```
    Box_Middle1 bm1;
    onCreate(){
        ...
        bm1 = new Box_Middle1(this);
        ...
    }
```

Objects that use system service has their own life cycle. Read the life cycle of Activity [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Comment: Didn't work, I did this: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1b7d38461585fd151005)

Comment: @user3808697 you are not doing it right, you **must** read the android tutorial, because you don't know the android basics.

Comment: Sorry, Java really confuses me sometimes, I just stick with the C++ method of coding...

Comment: I updated the answer in case it helps. Better to follow the link I put on the answer.

Comment: Thanks @mek, I'll check out that link

Answer (score 0):

Seems from your logcat that calling the method

```
bm1.MiddleCard();
```

in the onStart() instead of onCreate() of your Activity must do the trick.

Comment: I tried `@Override
    public void onStart()
    {
        bm1.MiddleCard();
    }` And the same error appears

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's what you get, when you are not starting with tutorials. You are trying to create activity in another activity and call it's method. We don't do this in Android. We can't do this in Android. Actually, we don't do such things on any platform:). Consider reading few tutorials about Android development on [Developer Android](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is not in MainActivity for sure , i just run your code in my emulator it works fine (i just commented your code inside MiddleCard() method). Put your code of Card class then might be anyone can help you in this. And Check if you are not using any System Services before OnCreate().

Comment: Did you even use the library? Thanks for experimenting, I was playing with the code and it's working now